# Oracle OCI how to connect to VS2017

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

Sorry for my English.

Please, help:
For the third day I’m trying to understand how to connect the OSI to Bisual Studio 2017, but I can’t understand how.
I read two instructions:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnoci/instant-client.html#GUID-2F3D53E5-0743-4F0C-9A47-FA06C12C6607
2. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14250/ociadwin.htm

The first says that only these three .dll are needed:
Table 2-4 Instant Client Light Shared Libraries for Microsoft Windows
oci.dll
oraociicus19.dll
orannzsbb19.dll

The second link already says that you need some kind of .lib files and header:

Linking OCI Applications for Windows
The OCI calls are implemented in dynamic link libraries (DLLs) that Oracle provides. The DLLs are located in the ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\bin directory and are part of the Required Support Files (RSFs).
Oracle only provides the oci.lib import library for use with the Microsoft Compiler. Borland compiler is also supported by Oracle for use with OCI. Oracle recommends that applications must always link with oci.lib to avoid re-linking or compilation with every release.
When using oci.lib with the Microsoft Compiler, you do not have to indicate any special link options.

and

Compiling and Linking an OCI Program with the Oracle XA Library
To compile and link an OCI program:
Compile program.c by using Microsoft Visual C++ or the Borland compiler, making sure to include ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\rdbms\xa in your path.
oraxa10.lib
ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\rdbms\xa
oci.lib

I am completely confused about what and how to do, what and how to connect, which dll, lib and header files to connect :(((((((((((((

Comment: What exactly are you trying to build?  Where will it run?  You may or may not find it easier to work with https://github.com/oracle/odpi or OCILIB.

Comment: Christopher Jones, thank you. It will be run on the windows. The problem for me is using OCILIB or ODPI-C, - still need to include the Oracle (instant client) drivers - and I just don’t understand how to connect them: ((((